# Why $\frac{F_{n+2}}{F_{n+1}}=1+\frac{F_n}{F_{n+1}}$?

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

Why $\frac{F_{n+2}}{F_{n+1}}=1+\frac{F_n}{F_{n+1}}$ (seems to) hold for every fibonacci number $F_n$?

Comment: Because $F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_n$

Comment: Multiply either side by $F_{n+1}$ to get the *property* of the series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know from the definition of the Fibonacci sequence that $F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_{n}$.

Suppose that $n$ is such that $F_{n+1}\neq 0$.

Dividing both sides of the recursive formula given in the definition by $F_{n+1}$ yields the result.